# Simple custom circle progress bar

Tags: android, android-progressbar

I've been using the circle progress bar in few places in my app.
As I'm implementing new design, I want to change the default circle image of the ProgressBar to some other image that would rotate in the same way.

Is there an easy way to override the circle image that would rotate (some xml definition or property), or am I have to create a rotate drawable and then start and stop it's animation?